# Store the results of a shell script in MySQL

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I am having a simple shell script which will grep a sequence from the log and displays the result on terminal when i run the script. How can i store this result into a MySQL table directly in the script itself?

For Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the two numbers to be added:" 
read n1 
read n2 
answer=$(($n1+$n2)) 
echo $answer
```

In the above example, how can i store n1, n2 and answer values in a database table.

Answer (score 1):

Create an insert query, and pipe it to stdin of mysql.

```
echo "insert into myTable values ($n1, $n2, $answer);" | mysql -u .. -h ..
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have a table to hold the value of n1, n2, answer

suppose you have "mytable" in database "test" with 3 columns for n1 n2 and answer, then just insert like this:

```
echo "insert into test.mytable values ($n1, $n2, $n1+$n2);" | mysql -h hostname -u username -ppassword
```

or

```
mysql -h hostname -u username -ppassword -e "insert into test.mytable values ($n1, $n2, $n1+$n2);"
```